# How to connect to an already running interactive Python session?

Tags: interoperability, python

[As Mathematica has the interoperability with Python](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html) since M11.2, with major improvements in M12.0, is it possible to connect to already running interactive Python sessions? For example, can we connect to a Python kernel started by Jupyter?

Can someone provide a pathway for doing that?

This question came to my mind since I feel certain operations are handy at one side and *vice versa* now and then.

Comment: Are you trying to access the same Python workspace both from a Jupyter notebook and from Mathematica?

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, that’s what I was thinking.

Comment: I suspect that the ExternalEvaluate stuff was not designed to allow this ... Being able to do this would be extremely useful though. I am putting a bounty on it, hoping that someone will at least investigate the limitations of ExternalEvaluate.

Comment: @Szabolcs do you specifically want this to work through `ExternalEvaluate`? Obviously you can do this if you can control Mathematica from python or python from Mathematica at the C++ level (both of which are of course very much so doable). Is it okay to have to type commands on both sides to get this to work? (i.e. start a `LinkObject` on the Mathematica side and connect to it from python).

Comment: "do you specifically want this to work through `ExternalEvaluate`" No, but that framework grew big enough that it would be hard to compete with at this point. "Is it okay to have to type commands on both sides to get this to work?" Yes, completely okay. That would be hard to avoid.

Comment: @b3m2a1I responded above, forgot to ping you.

Comment: What about the "Lightweight Grid" option for Mathematica, which allows you to search for available kernels.  Would that work?

Comment: @ILMostro_7 no. This is about an external kernel.

Comment: IPython and related have their own implementation of kernel/daemon specification to allow this type of functionality, so I suspect this is not going to be completely easy out-of-the-box. [Here is a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163964/python-is-it-possible-to-attach-a-console-into-a-running-process/35113682)

Comment: @CarlLange This question is not really about ipython/Jupyter. That's secondary. The main point is: can we connect to an already running interactive Python session? That could be running with Jupyter, just the command line, etc.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 This question is about connecting to a Python session. The Lightweight Grid has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I know - I meant that since ipython didn't use something already built-into the language, we may not be able to either. Or, since ipython has built something like this, perhaps we can leverage it.

Answer (score -3):

From Mathematica 12.0.0.0 Documentation Center entry for ExternalEvaluate: ExternalEvaluate[session,cmd] sends the command to a running session and does not exit the session.  For example:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"]
ExternalEvaluate[session, "x=1; x"]
ExternalEvaluate[session, "x=x+1; x"]
ExternalEvaluate[session, "x=x+1; x"]
DeleteObject[session]
```

will produce an ExternalSessionObject that you can expand to show the process details.  Successive outputs are 1, 2 and 3.

See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html

Comment: This does not answer the question at all ...

Comment: way to make new contributors feel welcome :(

Comment: I cast the first downvote to prevent the expiring bounty from being auto-awarded to an answer which does not answer the posed question at all.